# Cron job taking too much time and server doesnot allow unlimited exec time

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron job that extracts data from live feeds  the problem i am having is it takes around 25 mins to complete the execution  .

Web site is hosted at www.dreamhost.com they doesn't allow execution time to be unlimited although i have try to set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

and also:

```
set_time_limit 0 ;
```

Well I searched a lot  tried using `sleep()` command or tried scheduling it but of no use
server gives fatal 500 error.

I tried another way but i dont think its appropriate i am running 5 websites every time cron jobs run saving database of last record and continue like that but that is not helping much any professional solution to it ?

Comment: What exactly is your cronjob doing?

Comment: Break each job down into smaller jobs that do not take longer than the allowed max execution time.

Comment: while trying to break it but that doesnt work as per my website flow... @andewsi its extracting data from xml feeds

Comment: Why not trying fetching less information but more often. For example fetch every 5 minutes instead once hourly. 25 minutes sounds too long.

Comment: @ennen i have already mentioned that i tried using that procedure but its not working out for me as per my project flow

Comment: @AbdulBasit, okay then. What does mean `they doesn't allow execution time to be unlimited`? How they define unlimited. Can you set it to 1 hour for example?

Comment: @ennen means they allow only max 60 secs any thing more than that gives fatal error

Comment: If you don't want to change your script and you can't make it faster and you can't run more of them in parallel, then the only variable left to tweak is the max execution time. If you can't change this with your current host, change the host. *Something* in the group of *max time, parallelism, work size* has to give.

Comment: Very interesting hosting company... I don't think there is another way to make this work. 1) Rewrite somehow your code, so it becomes more elastic and could be separated. (But you said that there is not any way to do that) 2) Change the hosting company.

Comment: Do your things in `#!/usr/bin/env php` executable scripts, and set up a proper cron to hit it as needed. I seem to remember Dreamhost allowing you to do so from their control panel.

Comment: @deceze it cannot run faster cuz its extracting data it will takes its time according to websites its extracting data from

Comment: @denis ill try to check it and let u know if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so many research i found a method

go to this link 
http://sxi.sabrextreme.com/phpini

download and upload the file on your domain  . Run and Install it and in cgibin folder you can find php.ini file you can edit that .... I hope it helps